# Copy Exchange calendar into local calendar in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, exchange

To view an Exchange calendar, I use the lightning plugin for Thunderbird. Now I want to copy all entries from that Exchange calendar into a local calendar in Lightning, because the Exchange Server will be shut down in the next time. Is that possible? I have found some nasty possibilities, e.g., working with txt-files. Is there a handy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems you'll need the **Lightning** add-on for Thunderbird. With that, you can connect to the exchange server (if available) to fetch the calendar. You simply create a new calendar, choose "on the network" and then "exchange", and add the calendar with the following syntax:

```
https://domain\youracc@mail.server.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have updated my question...